# What do you call it when one is looking for what to eat in a particular food shop

Tags: vocabulary

Another new Japanese food shop has opened just next to our office bulding. They have prepared different kinds of cooked food for walk-in order.

The cooked foods are kept in good condition in several window cabinets.

Is there a specific term for when someone like me is looking around for what to eat in the food shop: is it called *food window shopping?*

Comment: You make eye contact and say something to the shop attendant. _Just looking_ is what I usually say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Browsing" is not specific to food but would be a good word to use for this activity (looking around to help you decide what to buy) in any shop.  ("Browse" is defined [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/browse).)

"Window shopping" (Merriam-Webster definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/window-shop)) suggests that you do not plan to buy anything.

Comment: Hi vstrong. Do you mean that it is grammatical to write, "I am browsing the food", or just "I am browsing" ?

Comment: Unless you are "browsing the Internet," "browse" generally is not transitive.  You would normally simply say "I am browsing."  Describing it to someone else, you could say "I was browsing in the new Japanese restaurant."